# How to prove the sample estimator of skewness is normally distributed of $N(0,\frac{6}{n})$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I got the statement from a lecture and it says that the estimator of skewness and kurtosis are

$\hat{S}=\frac{1}{(n-1)\hat{\sigma}^3}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^3$

$\hat{K}=\frac{1}{(n-1)\hat{\sigma}^4}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^4$

while $\hat{\sigma}$ would be the sample estimator of SD.

The lecture states that

$\hat{S}\sim N(0,\frac{6}{n})$

$\hat{K}-3\sim N(0,\frac{24}{n})$

Assuming that the sample is iid normally distributed.

Is there a proof of this??

Thanks a lot!!

The following are some effort I've been put using CLM:

I assume that $E(x)=\mu,E((x-\mu)^2)=\sigma^2$ are known.

So for each random sample $x_i$ the term $\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1)$ is standard normal.

Therefore $E\left(\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3\right)=0$

and $Var\left(\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3\right)=E\left(\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^6\right)=15$

So when CLM invokes I got a distribution of $\left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3\sim N(0,15)$ is that right?

Comment: it is not true !!

Answer (score 1):

It's not true, though it may be true asymptotically as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but may I ask for the proof??

Comment: Thx I fixed that...but I still need the proof.......

Comment: Asymptotically $S$ and $K$ are normally disributed, hence you just have to compute the mean and variance of $S$ and $K$, then invoke the central limit theorem.

Comment: In general, nonlinear functions of normal random variables should not be expected to be normal.

Comment: But assume $x$ standard normal $Var(x^3)=E(x^6)=15$ which is not 6.......

Comment: In the case $n=3$, it turns out that $\hat{K} = 1$.

Comment: well the formula is from a lecture slides, which I do not trust very much. The key is even if using CLM, the variance of estimated skewness is still not 6......

Comment: @Robertisreal May I ask for the proof of using CLM??

Comment: What do you mean by CLM?  Central Limit theoreM?

Comment: @robertisreal yep, central limited theorem. I also found that in wiki it says if $X$ is normally distributed, the it can be shown that $\sqrt {n}b_{1}{\xrightarrow {d}}N(0,6)$ while $b_{1}={\frac {m_{3}}{s^{3}}}={\frac {{\tfrac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{3}}{{\sqrt {{\tfrac {1}{n-1}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{2}}}^{\,3}}}={\frac {{\tfrac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{3}}{\left[{\tfrac {1}{n-1}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{2}\right]^{3/2}}}$ ......so i think the slides in some point make sense